# Xcode 4 skips coping app to device/simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

Whenever I attempt to run the debug version of my app, Xcode (4.0) compiles successfully, skips copying and just runs the old version. However if I clean first, Xcode copies just fine...

No relevant warnings, I triple checked the project and target build settings. Skip install is set to NO on main project and targets, all dependency projects have skip install set to YES.

Any ideas would be very welcome, recompiling every run is very painful.

Comment: Did you try deleting your old /build folder or pressing cmd+option+shift+K?

Comment: aka cleaning? Yes, like I said I did, it isn't an option to recompile for 10minutes every time. It seems to go away and come back at times...

Comment: Cleaning, yes, but a specific type of Cleaning, more than simply clicking Product > Clean.  I was thinking that there were previous builds that were conflicting with what XCode had cached in the /build directory.  Next time I won't contribute to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode's Clean command doesn't clean very thoroughly. There's still plenty of derived data retained after cleaning, something of which can cause these symptoms. I've had the same problem happen to me, where it kept running a old version of the app. To fix it I deleted the app from the simulator and deleted the Xcode derived data for the project.

To delete the derived data, quit Xcode. Locate the derived data in your account Library folder (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/), and delete the folder for this problematical project. Reopen the project in Xcode, and build and run.

Comment: Thanks, I tried nuking DerivedData and reinstalling xCode and what not... Usually it is ok, sometimes I need to facepalm and clean. I suppose it is as good as it will get. At least xCode 4.2 beta gives less trouble.